# Update already indexed images, what's the effect on SERPS on Google image search

Tags: seo

I have over 144,000 images indexed in google, however the current watermark is big and obtrusive and to provide a better user experience i wish to change it to a much smaller watermark. But since all these images are already indexed in google i was wondering what effect would it have on SERPS in google and Yahoo Image Searches as they are the biggest source of traffic to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately when you usually change images, Google treats it as a new image.  I recommend changing a small percentage and doing a test run for at least a few weeks to see what the changes are in your SERPs.

Comment: good point, i'll try on a few medium ranking images and see how they move.